# How to rerun useEffect when page is visible?

Tags: reactjs

A react app using hooks. In `useEffect` there is an api-call to populate content on page.
Each element fetched is clickable. And a click will open details for the clicked element in a new browser window/tab.

When working in the new window, the user can make changes on that object. The user will then close that tab or at least just go back to the main window/tab.

Question is how I can detect that the user is coming back to the main window. This is because I want to re-fetch data from API. Thus, I want to rerun `useEffect`.
While googling I found this:

```
https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-page-visibility
```

Is that really what I'm looking for? Reading the docs I'm not really sure if    that can be the solution to my issue. Is there another way to solve this?

Comment: I would think so. Either the visibility API or the window.blur/focus events seem like what you want and that npm package seems to implement a react wrapper for the former, so it seems the most elegant. Of course, the "right" way to do this would be to reactively push data from the backend on change and then react to that new data in react, which is exactly what Meteor does, but I don't get the sense that you have any such architecture set up.

Comment: Just putting this out there, [SWR](https://github.com/vercel/swr) does "revalidation on focus" out of the box.

Comment: @cbr, thanks for sharing. Yes, SWR is a step in the right direction, however it is still polling based, i.e., data is fetch even when nothing has changed, as opposed to push-based, sending data to the client only on change.

Answer (score 4):

You can use the [visibilitychange](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/visibilitychange_event) event to achieve that:

```js
const onVisibilityChange = () => {
  if (document.visibilityState === 'visible') {
    console.log("Tab reopened, refetch the data!");
  }
};

useLayoutEffect(() => {
  document.addEventListener("visibilitychange", onVisibilityChange);

  return () => document.removeEventListener("visibilitychange", onVisibilityChange);
}, []);
```

[Codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/sharp-mahavira-8x0n8?file=/src/App.js)

Comment: yes, that's what the npm package the OP referred to uses, too, and makes it readily available in a react context.

Answer (score 1):

With React 18 you can use 'visibilitychange' with react brand new hook useSyncExternalStore

```ts
export function useVisibilityChange(serverFallback: boolean) {
  const getServerSnapshot = () => serverFallback;
  const [getSnapshot, subscribe] = useMemo(() => {
    return [
      () => document.visibilityState === 'visible',
      (notify: () => void) => {
        window.addEventListener('visibilitychange', notify);

        return () => {
          window.removeEventListener('visibilitychange', notify);
        };
      },
    ];
  }, []);
```

[Gist with hook](https://gist.github.com/hmelenok/3c16c58cb3230838ff04a156d35cebb9)

P.S:Don't forget cross-browser usage